# Resource is not a ColorStateList exception

Tags: android

I did a search and found several questions on the topic, but none were good for me.

I'm trying to attach a styled color to a textview, and it keeps failing

**tehilim_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<com.karriapps.tehilimlibrary.utils.TehilimTextView   
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/titleColor"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/yehiTitle"
    android:layout_gravity="@integer/title_gravity"
    />   

<com.karriapps.tehilimlibrary.utils.TehilimTextView   
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="@string/yehiBefore"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="?attr/text_color"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

attr.xml

```
<attr name="text_color" format="reference"/>
```

style.xml

```
  <item name="text_color">@color/text_color</item>
```

text_color.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000000"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#000000" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#000000" />
   <item android:color="#000000"/>
 </selector>
```

Exception log

```
 04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): Process: com.karriapps.tehilimlibrary, PID: 3357
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class 
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at com.karriapps.tehilimlibrary.MainFragment$TehilimAdapter.getView(MainFragment.java:199)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:639)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     ... 45 more
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010075 a=-1}
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2237)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:960)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:618)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     at com.karriapps.tehilimlibrary.utils.TehilimTextView.(TehilimTextView.java:14)
    04-25 09:04:10.857: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):     ... 48 more
```

Comment: ?attr/text_color what is that

Comment: What is your `text_color` resource defined as?

Comment: I added those, for some reason they were deleted